# Why is my image not appearing in other views? (Rails)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-4

Here's my code for the application.html.erb:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="info.png" alt="Mountain View"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
            <li class="color-me">
              <a href="#" style="color:red">
            Contact Us
          </a>
            </li>
            <li class="color-me2" style="color:white">
            <%= link_to "About", root_path %>
            </li>
          </ul>

      </form>

    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

The navbar shows up in all my views but the image in the  tag disappears if I go to another URL other than the root URL. I placed the image in both /public and /assets/images.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found out how to do it. Just had to replace:

```
<img src="info.png" alt="Mountain View">
```

with:

```
<%= image_tag("info.png", :alt => "info") %>
```